# Can't find Pidgin in the Software Center of Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: pidgin

I can't find Pidgin in the Software Center of a freshly installed Ubuntu 16.10.
I recall having installed it from the Software Center earlier in Ubuntu 16.04.
I am relatively new to Linux and don't know how to compile it from source.

Comment: Make sure you have a fully updated system before using the Ubuntu Software. In terminal do `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` or just run Updates and install what's offered. Reboot. Pidgin should be there as it appears on mine. And, for the record, your options aren't "install from a store" or "compile from source". There's many software not in Ubuntu repositories but has packages for Debian/Ubuntu (*.deb) or RH derivatives (*.rpm) and PPAs, and...

Comment: Tried updating everything and now I can see it in the Software Center, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pidgin is available in the `universe` repository :

```
apt policy pidgin
pidgin:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:2.10.12-0ubuntu9
  Version table:
     1:2.10.12-0ubuntu9 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/universe amd64 Packages
```

You can install it by using a terminal command :

```
sudo apt install pidgin
```

Comment: Thanks! installed with your command line, then I looked for it again in the Software Center and now it shows there!